# When to use "is" vs. "does" when asking a question?

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs, inversion, do-support

When do I use *is* or *does* when I ask a question? For example,

> - Is your item still for sale?
> - Does your item still for sale?

I am not sure which one to use.

Comment: Turn your question back into a statement and see which one fits.  *The item is for sale* OR *The item does for sale.*  Since it is *The item is for sale* then the question is: *Is the item for sale?*

Answer (score 12):

When the verb in a statement is neither a primary auxiliary verb (*be, have, do*) nor a modal auxiliary verb (*will, would, can, could, may, might, shall, should, must, ought to, used to*), *do* is used to form a question from it. Thus, ‘You know where my house is’ becomes ‘Do you know where my house is?’

Meanwhile, when the verb in a statement is a primary auxiliary verb or a modal auxiliary verb, then a question is formed from it by placing the verb before the subject. That means that ‘Your item is still for sale’ becomes ‘Is your item still for sale?’

Comment: *Used you to go?

Comment: I normally insert _normally_ somewhere, and should have done so here. As it is, the BNC has no records for _used you to?_ used in this way. I don’t say no one ever says it, but my intuition is that _did you use to?_ is what most people would say.

Answer (score 3):

Barrie Englands answer is great. However, I have a feeling those seeking an answer will be at a level where they will also confused by the neither/nor structure.

For Primary auxiliaries (be/have/do), and Modal auxiliaries (will, would, can, could, may, might, shall, should, must, ought to, used to): 
Simply reverse the statement to form the question.

For all others use ‘do’ to form questions: 
Place the verb before the subject.

Comment: Hello Bob & welcome to the site! I have made some minor changes to your post, mainly, because referring to "the other answer" might become misleading once more answers are given. Unlikely in this case, but not impossible...

Comment: @Bob, «For _be/have/do_ — simply reverse the statement to form the question», it sounds like «You have a book → Have you a book?», but in fact it should be «Do you have a book?».