# "Does" question versus "is" question

Tags: meaning, questions, do-support

Could you explain to me which is correct (or if they are both correct)? What are the differences in meaning between these sentences?

> Is this version supposed to be fixed by us?
>
> Does this version supposed to be fixed by us?

I am a bit confused.
Thanks!

Comment: [Related](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10888/when-to-use-is-vs-does-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

> Is this supposed to be fixed by us?

This is the grammatically correct version since the affirmative statement is:

> This version is supposed to be fixed by us.

However, I don't know why you would use the passive voice here.  The best, most direct version is

> Are we supposed to fix this version?

Comment: There is a good case for using the passive voice: it draws attention to question of whose responsibility it is, rather than whether it should be fixed.
For example at a meeting, I would be more inclined to ask "Is this supposed to be fixed by us?" vs. "Are we supposed to fix this, or are you"?