# Is the sentence "I've decided to check my Facebook account one time at the day" correct?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, phrase-request, time

If I want to do something repeatedly every day for about 15 minute. What should I say?
For example, is the sentence "I've decided to check my Facebook account one time at the day" correct?

Comment: What thing do you mean? The question is still vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use exercise as an example:

- I exercise once daily
- I exercise everyday
- I exercise everyday for 15 minutes
- I exercise everyday at 1pm for 15 minutes

The grammar structure is:
Subject, Verb, count, time, duration

This is the simplest way to express the idea you are trying to express.

**EDIT:** Bonus lesson: (Nouns are bold, verbs are italic, adjectives are normal, Is/does are normal as well).

Your question should read: Is **the sentence “I've decided to check my Facebook account one time at the day”** correct?

The rule:

Does:

- Does **noun** *verb* adjective
- Does **this sentence** *look* correct?

Is:

- Is **noun** adjective?
- Is **this sentence** correct?

This post may help you as well: [When to use "is" vs. "does" when asking a question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10888/when-to-use-is-vs-does-when-asking-a-question)

**Conclusion:**

The sentence you are looking for is: "I have decided to check my Facebook account once daily." or "I have decided to check my Facebook account one time a day."

Comment: Thanks. Is "once daily" natural in daily life? why there are not many sentences by "once daily", When I google it. I see it is used by drug ,...

Comment: Once daily is the same as "one time a day" So you could just as easily say "I do something one time a day." "Once Daily" is used to describe how frequently you should take certain types of medication. This is the same as "I take medication one time a day." They are both correct.

Comment: @Toby, Everyday is an adjective. You can't use it here. It should be every day instead.

Comment: I have no problem with this answer, but accepting it in less than four hours [might be a little fast](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer). I also agree that "once daily" seems a  bit formal for Facebook checking. One other possibility (if it's true): _I've decided to check my Facebook account **at the same time every day**._

Answer (score 3):

If you do an activity only one time during each day, you would say "I've decided to check my Facebook account once a day."

If you do it two times each day, you would say "twice a day."

Three times would be "three times a day," four times would be "four times a day," etc.

There is an old-fashioned word, "thrice," which means three times, but it is hardly heard anymore.

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer? ELL is mostly interested in answers that help someone learning English as a foreign language by explaining _why_ the correct usage makes sense so they can apply what they learn to other circumstances.